# How to check a point if it is inside a polygon in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, polygon

I am implementing a web application where I need to check if a given point is within a polygon in MySQL table?

I am using ASP.net with MySQL. I am trying to use the following SQL statement

```
SELECT REGION_USER_ID FROM region WHERE (ST_Within(point(-23, 1), geom));
```

with my table and get the following error. 
(FUNCTION ST_Within DOES NOT exist)

[image]

What is the issue here?
Also, is geom is a keyword ? (I got this from a site but can not remember where)

My polygon coordinates are in the table written with the following statement : (It's working and I can read and see)

```
INSERT INTO region (REGION_POLYGON) VALUES (PolygonFromText(@Parameter1))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the version of your mysql?

Comment: Mysql version 8. VS 2017.

Comment: Reading more found that GEOM is another set variable. Tested that in MySQL WB. However since I am checking the point against the Table data, how could I eliminate that? I need to find the records that this point resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is if someone is looking for the solution :

```
string Query = @"SELECT " +
                                    "A," +
                                    "B,"+
                                    "C,"+
                                    "D,"+
                                    "E,"+
                                    "F"+
                                "FROM user " +
                                "INNER JOIN State ON " +
                                    "A=B AND C=@Parameter1 " +
                                "INNER JOIN Country ON " +
                                    "CONTAINS(REGION_POLYGON, point(@Parameter2, @Parameter3)=1)";
```

Parameter2 : Logitude
Parameter3 : Latitude

Thanks.